# Facing issue in usage of 'withApplies' in aggregate function using the library "MacFJA/php-redisearch"

Tags: php, laravel, aggregate, redisearch

#### Aggregate Raw query

`FT.AGGREGATE indexName "@geofield:[-83.81373 34.3755452645611 20 mi]" LOAD 1 @geofield APPLY "@cc_sum * ( 20 - (geodistance(@geofield, -83.81373, 34.3755452645611)) / 20)" as ccSumCalcValue APPLY 1 as test GROUPBY 1 @test REDUCE SUM 1 @ccSumCalcValue as weightedSum`

#### Aggregate query using the "MacFJA/php-redisearch"

```
$query = '@geofield:[-83.81373 34.3755452645611 20 mi]';
 $resultAggregate = $aggregate
    ->withIndexName('indexName ')
    ->withLoad(['geofield', 'cc_sum', 'if_fat'])
    ->withQuery($query)
    ->withApplies(['@cc_sum * ( 20 - (geodistance(@geofield, -83.81373, 34.3755452645611)) / 20)' => 'ccSumCalcValue'])
    ->addGroupBy(['ccSumCalcValue'], [])
    ->execute();
```

I am not able to do the following command from raw aggregate query using this library

`APPLY 1 as test GROUPBY 1 @test REDUCE SUM 1 @ccSumCalcValue as weightedSum`

Can someone help me out to do this command using this library

Answer (score 1):

Copied from https://github.com/MacFJA/php-redisearch/issues/21#issuecomment-965615182

---

> Here the code to have the same output as your raw query (order of
> instructions are not in the same exact order):
>
> ```php
> $aggregate
>     ->withIndexName('indexName ')
>     ->withLoad(['@geofield'])
>     ->withQuery($query)
>     ->withApplies(['@cc_sum * ( 20 - (geodistance(@geofield, -83.81373, 34.3755452645611)) / 20)' => 'ccSumCalcValue', '1 ' => 'test'])
>     ->addGroupBy(['test'], [MacFJA\RediSearch\Aggregate\Reducer::sum('ccSumCalcValue', 'weightedSum')]);
> ```
>
> ---
>
> There is indeed a small issue with the APPLY `1 as test` as the value
> of the applier (`1`) is not consider as a string, but with an extra space,
> the value is forced to be a string